# Uploadify. Upload works, but does not save to folder

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

I'm struggling with uploadify at the moment. I've followed the documentation, but for the life of my I can't get the file to upload to the folder.

I am using MAMP on OSX. When uploading I can see the upload bar, no errors on the JS console in chrome. The tmp folder is 777.

**views/upload.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/uploadify/uploadify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/uploadify/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'uploader'  : '<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script'    : '<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/uploadify/uploadify.php',
            'cancelImg' : '<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/uploadify/cancel.png',
            'auto'      : true
        });
    });


</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file">
</body>
</html>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tmp';
$targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile);

}
```

Comment: You probably need to add a `/` to $targetPath

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Pekka.

Comment: no problem. I'll add it as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add a `/` to $targetPath:

```
$targetPath = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tmp/';
```

In general, one way to debug this stuff is to create a normal file upload in a form. That way, you can do test outputs in your upload script and see them. Once everything works on server side, switch back to using SWFUpload on the client side.

Comment: Worked. It's always the simple solutions that cause the most headaches.

Comment: @GV1 one more note: Using the user-provided file name to store the file on your server is a security risk and can malfunction (e.g. if the file name contains characters that your file system doesn't allow). It's safer to use a self-generated name (and store the user provided name in a database, if it is needed later)

Comment: Thanks for the concern @Pekka. I'm actually using CodeIgniters file upload class which encrypts file names and restricts file types. I was testing Uploadify with the example above.